# Limit question for two functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits

I have a question about limits:

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $r : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. If

$$ \lim_{x \to h} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$$

Are the following true?

a) $$ \lim_{x \to h} \frac{1}{f(x)} - \frac{1}{g(x)} = 0$$b
) $$ \lim_{x \to h} r(f(x))-r(g(x)) = 0$$

Comment: Are $f, g, h$ continuous functions?

Comment: @Maadhav That's not a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider following counter-examples

$a)$ Let $h=0$ and $f(x)=sinx$, $g(x)=x$

Then

$\lim_{x\to h} \frac{1}{f(x)}- \frac{1}{g(x)}$doesn’t exist.

$b)$ If $h=\infty$ and $f(x)=x+1, g(x)=x, r(x)=x$

Here also corresponding limit doesn’t converge to $0$.

Comment: Does $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}x =1 ?$

Comment: @Maadhav Now I have edited the example. Have a look!